# How to open relative information onClick on dynamically created child

Tags: javascript

I am creating timers for workers. A user can add worker with some time. After that it will create a countdown timer for that worker. Start time and target time is saved on database so i am starting timer according to that. And the timer is worked fine. Now i want that if i click on any of the created child it should i want to call my php with POST id of the Work which is added on child creation and then open detailed information of the work which was filled when worker was added. So basically i want help in post WorkID of the selected child on click and call my php script.

**On Page load i am getting data like this**

```
function GetMachineSinger() {

var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'php/StitchTimerSinger.php';
http.open('GET', url, true);

http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
    var data = this.responseText;
    var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(data);
    for(var i=0;i<jsonResponse.length;i++){
    var index = jsonResponse[i];
    var empname = index["EmployeeName"];
    var hour = index["Hour"];
    var minute = index["Min"];
    var second = index["Sec"];
    var available = index["Available"];
    var id = index["WorkID"];

    if(available<50){
    addEmployee(id,empname,hour,minute,second);
    }
    document.getElementById("avlmc").innerHTML = available;
    }

}
}
http.send();
}
```

**addEmployee()**

```
function addEmployee(id,emp,hr,mi,sec)
        { 
            var employee = new Employee(id,emp,hr,mi,sec);
            display.appendChild(employee.domObj);
            employee.startTimer();
        }
    class Employee
        {   
            constructor(id,name,hr,min,sec)
            {
                var self=this;

                this.timer;
                this.timeInSec;
                this.domObj=document.createElement("div");
                this.timeSpan=document.createElement("span");

                this.domObj.style.backgroundColor = '#4CA';
                this.domObj.style.border = 'none';
                this.domObj.style.height = '100px';
                this.domObj.style.width = '100px';
                this.domObj.style.color = 'white';
                this.domObj.style.padding = '20px';
                this.domObj.style.textAlign = 'center';
                this.domObj.style.textDecoration = 'none';
                this.domObj.style.display = 'inline-block';
                this.domObj.style.fontSize = '26px';
                this.domObj.style.borderRadius = '50%';
                this.domObj.style.margin = '20px';
                this.domObj.style.justifyContent = "center";

                this.timeInSec=hr*60*60+min*60+parseInt(sec);
                this.timeSpan.innerHTML=hr+":"+min+":"+sec;
                this.domObj.innerHTML=name+"<br>";
                this.domObj.appendChild(this.timeSpan);
               // console.log("0:"+this.timeInSec);
            }               
            startTimer()
            {
                this.timer=setInterval(this.updateTime.bind(this),1000);
            }
            updateTime()
            {
                var hr,min,sec,temp;


                if (this.timeInSec<=0)
                {
                    clearInterval(this.timer);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.timeInSec--;
                    //console.log("1:"+this.timeInSec);
                    sec=this.timeInSec % 60;
                    temp=this.timeInSec-sec;
                    temp/=60;
                    //console.log("2:"+temp);
                    min=temp % 60;
                    temp-=min;
                    hr=temp/60;

                    this.timeSpan.innerHTML=hr+":"+min+":"+sec;
                    if (min<10 && hr<1){
                    this.domObj.style.backgroundColor = '#ef5350';   
                    }

                }
            }
}
```

Comment: You can add `onclick=doSomething(id)` to your div when adding an employee. And in the method `doSomething(id)` you can call php POST.

Comment: I added `this.domObj.onclick = WorkerInfo(id);` but WorkerInfo(id) is call onLoad @NarekTootikian

Comment: Try `this.domObj.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            // do something
        });`

Comment: Yes now it is calling but need 1 last help. I am calling another function onclick and i want to open its response in new page but with same tab. How can i achieve this in onreadystatechange? @NarekTootikian

Comment: Do you need something like popup window?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
this.domObj.addEventListener('click', function (event) { 
  // do something 
  //for opening new window
  let w = window.open('about:blank','name','height=200,width=150');
      // w.document.open()
      w.document.write('any HTML');
      w.document.close();
});
```